# Palpal Mass Payment Responce

Tags: php, paypal

I am using Paypal Masspayment API and its working just fine, but I want to know how much fees I had paid for transaction, or transaction was domestic or international, But I am only getting this array in response

```
Array
(
     [TIMESTAMP] => 2015%2d02%2d03T05%3a31%3a25Z
     [CORRELATIONID] => 1bccbfad582e7
     [ACK] => Success
     [VERSION] => 51%2e0
     [BUILD] => 15110743
)
```

Is it even possible with Mass Pay API ?

Or if there is any way to get calculated result my website from this mass payment fees calculator ? 
https://www.paypal.com/np/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_batch-payment-overview-outside

I will prefer solution written in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal doesn't share any confidential information so it may not be possible, but you can calculate the fees using curl, here is the working code

```
    $url = "https://www.paypal.com/np/cgi-bin/webscr";
    $data=array(
      "cmd" => '_calc-masspay-fee',
      "sender_country" => $Country,
      "receiver_country" => 'GB',
      "currency_code" => Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
      "curr_list_reqd" => 1
    );

    $cr = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);       // Get returned value as string (dont put to screen)
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); // Spoof the user-agent to be the browser that the user is on (and accessing the php $
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_POST, true);                 // Tell curl that we are posting data
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);          // Post the data in the array above
    $output = curl_exec($cr); 

    $output = json_decode($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this would be to setup an [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) solution.  You would get an IPN with more details when you make a MassPay transaction.  Here's an example of one:

```
Array
(
    [payer_id] => ATSCG2QMC9KAU
    [payment_date] => 09:23:59 Jan 28, 2015 PST
    [payment_gross_1] => 10.00
    [payment_gross_2] => 10.00
    [payment_gross_3] => 10.00
    [payment_status] => Processed
    [receiver_email_1] => andrew_1342623385_per@angelleye.com
    [receiver_email_2] => usb_1329725429_biz@angelleye.com
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [receiver_email_3] => andrew_1277258815_per@angelleye.com
    [mc_currency_1] => USD
    [masspay_txn_id_1] => 1M205262R4107805K
    [mc_currency_2] => USD
    [masspay_txn_id_2] => 95942086WL824160N
    [mc_currency_3] => USD
    [masspay_txn_id_3] => 21W68993Y67646416
    [first_name] => Drew
    [unique_id_1] => 
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [unique_id_2] => 
    [unique_id_3] => 
    [payer_status] => verified
    [verify_sign] => AJ-yMngskqU0wKMAcE2BE6cQ.uxhA3cw3neNnb2W68Ic2ZwqkxjYIgMg
    [payer_email] => sandbo_1215254764_biz@angelleye.com
    [payer_business_name] => Drew Angell's Test Store
    [last_name] => Angell
    [status_1] => Completed
    [status_2] => Completed
    [status_3] => Completed
    [txn_type] => masspay
    [mc_gross_1] => 10.00
    [mc_gross_2] => 10.00
    [mc_gross_3] => 10.00
    [payment_fee_1] => 0.20
    [residence_country] => US
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [payment_fee_2] => 0.20
    [payment_fee_3] => 0.20
    [mc_fee_1] => 0.20
    [mc_fee_2] => 0.20
    [mc_fee_3] => 0.20
    [ipn_track_id] => 205e7228cfda3
)
```

That particular MassPay had 3 payments included on it, so you can see separate data for each one that you could loop through and process accordingly.

There are plenty of PHP classes available for IPN on GitHub and/or Packagist and available for use with Composer if you happen to be using that.  If you happen to be using WordPress I'd take a look at [PayPal IPN for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/), which would get you up-and-running very quickly, and then you could easily extend it to handle your own needs.